# Reading Headers and Cookies

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Is there anyway to read Reqeuest/Response Headers in `requests`? I have to read a page which sets cookie when access. I need to read that value

Answer (score 1):

No, BeautifulSoup is used to handle HTML, not the whole response.

Refer to [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) if you need to handle headers.

===UPD===

well, first you need to know that cookie is just one field in headers.

to handle headers in request, see http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#custom-headers

to handle headers in response, see http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#response-headers

Requests also provide a parsed object for cookies, see http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#cookies

Comment: Sorry, Updated Question